# Pandas Merge multiple rows into a single row based on columns

Tags: python, pandas

How can the column values be added after searching the dataframe by index, the number of columns is formed dimamically.
Dataframe searches go through the list.

```
listgroup = [some list]
df[df.index.isin([200100000004,200100000005])]
```

.

```
               column1    column2    column3    columnN
200100000001    1        20         1              3
200100000009    1        55         1              3
200100000004    1        30         2              12
200100000005    1        50         3              4
```

result

```
                           column1    column2    column3    columnN
200100000004,200100000005   2        80         5              16
```

Comment: is there any logic for grouping or are you planning to group every 2 rows? can you add some more details to the question body with explanation of what you want to do..

Comment: no, not every two lines, but only those that match the search results `df[df.index.isin(listgroup)] `

Comment: Sorry I still am not clear, can you add an example for `listgroup = [some list]` and explain what you are looking for. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63114266/edit) your question to include these details

Comment: Corrected, so I think more clearly

Comment: Do you want to add up rows given in the listgroup?

Comment: I want to sum column values, after search

Answer (score 0):

1. filter df based on `isin()`
2. assign a column *foo* that can be used for `groupby()` and a column *IDL* that can be used to construct concatenated index
3. build instructions to `agg()` using a list comprehension
4. clean up

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[200100000001,200100000009,200100000004,200100000005],"column1":[1,1,1,1],"column2":[20,55,30,50],"column3":[1,1,2,3],"columnN":[3,3,12,4]})
df = df.set_index("ID")
listgroup = [200100000004,200100000005]
df[df.index.isin(listgroup)].assign(foo=1,IDL=lambda x: x.index).groupby("foo")\
    .agg({**{"IDL":lambda x: ",".join([str(i) for i in list(x)])},
          **{col:"sum" for col in df.columns}
         }).reset_index().drop(columns=["foo"]).set_index("IDL")
```

**output**

```
                           column1  column2  column3  columnN
IDL                                                          
200100000004,200100000005        2       80        5       16
```